# Python scrapy crawlspider x-forwarded-for header

Tags: python, scrapy

My simple crawlspider is bellow. How can I add X-Forwarded-For to this crawler? The X-Forwarded-For should be for all pages which will be crawled.

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http.request import Request

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'spidy'
    allowed_domains = ['website.com', 'www.website.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.website.com/']
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/uk/', )), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

P.S. I found a way to do it via settings.py but is there a way via the spider ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the `process_request` function in the `Rule` object as below

```
rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/uk/', )), callback='parse_item', follow=True, process_request='add_header'),)

def add_header(self, request, response):
   request.headers['X-Forwarded-For'] = 'the_header_value'
   return request
```

See the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule) for further information.